# How to work with an 'x' variable like in math?

Tags: java, variables

How can I work with an 'x' variable like in math?

I need to write a code that determines a polynomial function. For example if the input data is 2, 4, 8, 9 then the function would be 2 + 4x + 8x^2 + 9x^3.

Now I do know how to process the input data etc. but I don't know how to declare a variable that has no value, for example I declared a variable x = double, but I still have to initialize it but I don't want to give x a value at this point yet?

So how can I write a method that for example returns 'x' to the power of something?

This is what I have at the moment (it still doesn't work of course)

```
public class Interpol {

public static void main(String []args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //get user input (polynomial coefficients and interval values x1 and x2)
        ArrayList<Double> polynomialCoefficients = new ArrayList<Double>();
        int amountCoefficients = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            polynomialCoefficients.add(scanner.nextDouble());
            amountCoefficients++;
        }
        String in = scanner.next();
        double x1 = scanner.nextDouble();
        double x2 = scanner.nextDouble();

        //call method f to determine the polynomial function
        double x;
        double[] termsFunction = new double[amountCoefficients];
        for (int i = 0; i < polynomialCoefficients.size(); i++) {
            termsFunction[i] = f(i, polynomialCoefficients.get(i));
        }

        //call method findaroot to determine the root


        //print result


}

//determine function of which a root is to be found
public static double f(int i, double polynomialCoefficient) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return polynomialCoefficient;
    }
    double x;
    return polynomialCoefficient * (Math.pow(x, i));
}

/*  //rounds off d to 3 decimals 
public static double rnd(double d) {

}

//returns a root in this interval, recursive function
 public static double findaroot{double x1, double x2) {

}*/
```

}

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  If it has no value, you can't do anything with it.  `2x` has no value either.

Comment: I'm not sure you fully understand how math actually works.  If you're returning "x to the power of something" what do you actually expect the result to be?  Are you calculating the value or not?  You can't determine the result based on `x` if you don't have a value for `x`.

Comment: As stated in the assignment I've been given, I am asked to write three methods, one method to determine the polynomial function, one method to calculate the value and one method to print the results. So for the first method, which is the one I'm working on, I apparently don't have to calculate the value yet, I just have to determine the polynomial function, so x wouldn't have a value yet, I mean I can't say that x is equal 7 or something since that is determined in the second method, where I have to calculate the value for a lot of different varying values of x (I have to find the root).

Comment: "One method to calculate the value", you probably want something like `public double eval(double x) { return x*x + 3 * x - 7; }` your x will be a argument of a method.

Comment: Do you know any programming at all? Have you tried anything? Have you read any **basic** guides on how programming works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a *Class* of *objects* that represent polynomials. The class will store the coefficients in an instance variable, and provide a *method* to evaluate the polynomial at a given value.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //get user input (polynomial coefficients and interval values x1 and x2)
        ArrayList<Double> polynomialCoefficients = new ArrayList<Double>();
        int amountCoefficients = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            polynomialCoefficients.add(scanner.nextDouble());
            amountCoefficients++;
        }

        Polynomial polynomial = new Polynomial(polynomialCoefficients);

        String in = scanner.next();

        while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            double x = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("f(" + x + ") = " + polynomial.evaluate(x));
        }
    }

    static class Polynomial {

        ArrayList<Double> _coefficients;

        public Polynomial(ArrayList<Double> coefficients) {
            _coefficients = coefficients;
        }

        public double evaluate(double x) {
            double result = 0;

            // This algorithm is called Horner’s rule. See Knuth.
            for (int i = _coefficients.size() - 1; i>= 0; i--) {
                result *= x;
                result += _coefficients.get(i);
            }

            return result;
        }

    }

}
```

If I run this program and type `2 4 8 9 x 2.7`, then it prints `f(2.7) = 248.267`, which is [correct according to Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+%2B+4x+%2B+8x%5E2+%2B+9x%5E3+%2F.+x-%3E+2.7).

Comment: *class of objects* please learn correct terminology before you answer.